# ASP.NET Core invalid token when confirming email but token seems valid

Tags: c#, token, identity, asp.net-core-webapi, email-confirmation

I have ASP.NET Core web api project and I need to confirm email. Everything is working fine and generated token and token received in ConfirmEmail() method are equal. Token seems valid but result gives invalid token:

```
    var result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
```

Generating token:

```
        var code = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
        var email = user.Email;
        await emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(email, callbackUrl);
```

EmailConfirmationLink() and SendEmailConfirmationAsync() methods:

```
    public static string EmailConfirmationLink(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string userId, string code, string scheme)
    {
        var result = urlHelper.Action(
            action: "ConfirmEmail",
            controller: "ApplicationUsers",
            values: new { userId, code },
            protocol: scheme);

        return result;
    }

    public static Task SendEmailConfirmationAsync(this IEmailSender emailSender, string email, string link)
    {
        return emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email, "Confirm your email",
            $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(link)}'>Confirm email</a>");
    }
```

ConfirmEmail() method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
            if (userId == null || code == null)
            {
                // ....
            }
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }               
            var result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
```

Comment: The the value of the code directly in the database and compare it to the value you receive. Maybe there is a mismatch between the code and the user.

Comment: Are you doing anything else to the user after generating the token or before attempting to use it?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I am updating user before generating token but nothing after generating

Comment: @jirka  i've found no mismatch so far

Comment: Can you elaborate on the user updating you've mentioned?

Comment: yes user is updated and then token is generated for this user

Comment: Are you able to test what happens if you *don't* update the user first? If not, please include the code for this update process and how it fits in with the code generation.

Comment: Thanks Kirk ! It's working if I make email confirmation separately (first I have to update user and once it's done I can make email confirmation), pls write the answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Seeing as this problem seems to have been solved, I'll add this as a comment only: {HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(link)}  is not right, best I can tell. It worked on my Windows machine (??) but when running on Linux I found out the hard way that this snippet should (??) be {HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(link)}

Comment: OMG!! This saved me from 2 hours debugging!!!..My error is the same invalid token because I get my confirmEmail Token before registration.. so after registration the token changed internally.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue and i tried the answers above and till got no luck.
Setting the isHtml parameter to true in the SendAsync method fixed my problem.

```
_emailService.SendAsync(vm.Email, "Click the link below to validate.", $"<a href=\"{link}\">Validate email</a>",true);
```